# One XML converted into multiple XML in Mule

Tags: xslt, mule, mule-studio

I have one xml file like below.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<machineDetail>
  <machineData>
    <machineNumber>00000001</machineNumber>
    <concessionUnitType>NONE</concessionUnitType>
    <machineType>SCHAERER</machineType>
    <customerNumber>69990005</customerNumber>
    <equipmentLocation>REM</equipmentLocation>
    <installedDate>2013-08-01T00:00:00.000+0000</installedDate>
  </machineData>
  <machineData>
    <machineNumber>00001024</machineNumber>
    <concessionUnitType>NONE</concessionUnitType>
    <machineType>IBS4</machineType>
    <customerNumber>69990005</customerNumber>
    <equipmentLocation>1024</equipmentLocation>
    <installedDate>2011-09-29T00:00:00.000+0000</installedDate>
  </machineData>
</machineDetail>
```

Now I have to divide into 2 xmls having data like

**1.xml**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
    <machineDetail>
      <machineData>
        <machineNumber>00000001</machineNumber>
        <concessionUnitType>NONE</concessionUnitType>
        <machineType>SCHAERER</machineType>
        <customerNumber>69990005</customerNumber>
        <equipmentLocation>REM</equipmentLocation>
        <installedDate>2013-08-01T00:00:00.000+0000</installedDate>
      </machineData>
</machineDetail>
```

**2.xml**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
  <machineDetail>
    <machineData>
        <machineNumber>00001024</machineNumber>
        <concessionUnitType>NONE</concessionUnitType>
        <machineType>IBS4</machineType>
        <customerNumber>69990005</customerNumber>
        <equipmentLocation>1024</equipmentLocation>
        <installedDate>2011-09-29T00:00:00.000+0000</installedDate>
      </machineData>
    </machineDetail>
```

This has to be completed in Mule. Please suggest the xslt in this case. I am a new guy in Mule.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following flow should do what you asked for.  You might need to do cleanup the namespaces if needed..

```
<mule xmlns:mulexml="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/xml"
xmlns:file="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file" xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core"
xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation"
xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-current.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file/current/mule-file.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/xml http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/xml/current/mule-xml.xsd">

 <mulexml:xslt-transformer name="xslt">
    <mulexml:xslt-text>
        <xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns="">
            <xsl:output method="xml"/>
            <xsl:template match="/">
            <machineDetail>
                  <xsl:copy-of select="." />
            </machineDetail>
            </xsl:template>
         </xsl:stylesheet>
    </mulexml:xslt-text>

</mulexml:xslt-transformer>

</mulexml:xslt-transformer>

<file:file-to-string-transformer name="File_to_String"
    doc:name="File to String" />
<flow name="testflowsFlow">
    <file:inbound-endpoint path="C:\Temp\mule\in"
        responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="File" />
    <file:file-to-string-transformer
        doc:name="File to String" />
    <splitter expression="#[xpath('//machineData')]" doc:name="Splitter"
        enableCorrelation="ALWAYS" />
    <mulexml:dom-to-xml-transformer
        doc:name="DOM to XML" />
    <file:outbound-endpoint transformer-refs="xslt"
        path="C:\Temp\mule\out" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="File"
        outputPattern="#[message.outboundProperties.MULE_CORRELATION_SEQUENCE].xml" />
</flow>
```

Comment: Thanks @Cuball. However the files format is still containing <machineDetail xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core"><machineData xmlns="">

Comment: The newly created files contain the header like above while it should be <machineDetail> <machineData>. Any suggestions on how to remove it.

Comment: I simplified the xlst a bit too, see above

Answer (score 0):

Use a splitter in conjuction with an xpath MEL expression: like so:

```
<splitter expression="#[xpath('//machineDetail/machineData')]" doc:name="Splitter"/>
```

This will create two XML document like so:

```
<machineData>
        <machineNumber>00001024</machineNumber>
        <concessionUnitType>NONE</concessionUnitType>
        <machineType>IBS4</machineType>
        <customerNumber>69990005</customerNumber>
        <equipmentLocation>1024</equipmentLocation>
        <installedDate>2011-09-29T00:00:00.000+0000</installedDate>
      </machineData>
```

Then while the message is split use XSLT or similar to wrap the XML in an 
   `machineDetail` element

Comment: Can you please put the flow which you created for this purpose.